# Inline assembly: jump to a known function stored in a constant static pointer

Tags: assembly, gcc, clang, x86-64, inline-assembly

Given a known constant static function pointer such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int (* const puts_ptr)(char const*) = &puts;
```

I would like to use inline assembly with `puts_ptr` as an input to generate `jmp puts`.

This:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 static int (* const puts_ptr)(char const*) = &puts;
void callputs(char const*X){ 
    __asm volatile ("jmp %c0\n" : : "i"(puts_ptr));
    __builtin_unreachable();
 }
```

works, with the i (immediate) constraint and the c (print without a dollar sign) modifier
works on GCC, but doesn't compile on clang.

Is there a clang version of this?

https://godbolt.org/z/vsbWEbsqT

Clang doesn't even process this:

```
__asm volatile ("jmp %c0\n" : : "i"(puts));
```

or even:

```
__asm volatile ("jmp %0\n" : : "r"(puts));
```

(where gcc generates and address load and a register-indirect jump).

As for recognizing known values of `const statics`, neither gcc nor clang seem to have a problem with object values:

```
static int const x  = 42; //could also use an enum here to guarantee const-expr-ness
static int const*const p  = &x; //can't use an enum 
int retint_x(void){ __asm volatile ("ret;" : : "a"(x)); __builtin_unreachable(); } //return 42; ✓; no load from x
int *retptr(void){ __asm volatile ("ret;" : : "a"(p));  __builtin_unreachable();} //return &x ✓; no load from p
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000 <retint_x>:
   0:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000006 <retptr>:
   6:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax    7: R_X86_64_32  .rodata
   b:   c3                      retq
```

(I can't use `constexpr` (for use with a macro meant for plain C) or a `#define` (the constants are outputted by a macro so can't use a define (enum, at best, but those can only store plain integers)) to hold to compiler to recognizing to static consts' values as known, but it's alright if they practically do with at least with optimization on).

https://godbolt.org/z/hsT14G3Yj

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this can't be made to work portably at all.  `puts_ptr` may be qualified `const`, but it's not a constant expression.  Whether this compiles with gcc or not may even be dependent on optimisation level.  I strongly recommend against this kind of stuff as it usually explodes in your face.

Comment: If programming in C++ or C23, check if you can use `constexpr` for `puts_ptr` instead.

Comment: @fuz On clang it doesn't even work with `__asm volatile ("jmp %c0\n" : : "i"(puts)); ` -- I think that needs to work first before worrying about the compiler maybe not treating `static const`s as known (which both tend to recognize as known quite well, for object (non-funct-pointer) versions of this anyway).

Comment: As fuz said, your code that "works" with GCC depends on optimization level.  If you compile without optimization (or `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`), https://godbolt.org/z/Eh4MdE97K shows that GCC does `push rbp` ... before the `jmp`, so  the stack will be misaligned, and the return address `puts` sees (pointed-to by RSP on entry to it) will be the caller's saved RBP value.  Or with `-mno-red-zone`, probably `const void*X` will become the return address.

Comment: Also, if you actually call this function from anywhere else, it will inline and the `jmp` tailcall will end up in the middle of some other function, without doing anything to get the arg into RDI.  For both those reasons this needs to be `__attribute__((naked))` which implies noinline.  But GCC doesn't officially support Extended Asm statements (with constraints) in naked functions, although `"i"` constraints are likely to work.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve that you need inline asm for, instead of dereferencing a function pointer like `puts_ptr(x); return;` or `return puts_ptr(x)` in non-void functions whose return type is compatible with `int`?

Comment: @PeterCordes I do realize the dummy example is dummy. Here I define works as "jmp puts" is outputted. ;-) I realize frame pointers are emitted at -O0 and  `jmp puts` wouldn't run well with them. But I'm really only asking if there's a mechanism to generate `jmp function` from a pointer to that function. (It would save me some minor repetition between a macro declaring a struct with some associated constants and  a macro defining assembly-based "methods" for that struct.)

Comment: If building a PIE or shared library, do you need it to actually expand to `jmp puts@PLT` or `jmp [RIP + puts@GOTPCREL]?  Like `jmp %P0` to always print `foo@PLT` for symbol names when expanding an `"i"` constraint.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Generic-Operand-Modifiers)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. Interesting. When building with -fpic/-fPIC the i constraint on puts gets rejected, but directly used "jmp puts" works even from a shared lib—the linker indirects the call through the PLT just fine (as also mentioned in https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/ which also complains about compilers adding these suffixes). Looks like this is problematic area, and I'm going to stick with the slightly less DRY version.